# Plotting horizontal hyperbola/circle using fsolve, numpy, and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I was recently trying to plot a nonlinear decision boundary, and the function ended up being a partially horizontal hyperbola, where there were multiple y-values for a given x. Although I got it to work, I know there has to be a more pythonic or numpythonic way of plotting this line.

**Background**: The problem was a perceptron classifier on a set of inputs that were not linearly separable. In order to find this, the inputs were mapped to a general hyperbola function to increase the dimensionality to 5, and have these separable by a hyperplane. The equation for the decision boundary that will be plotted is 
    d(x) = w0 + w1xx + w2yy + w3xy + wx + w5y
Through the course of the perceptron's gradient descent, the values for w0-w5 are found, and the boundary is the x,y value when d(x)=0.

**Current implementation**: I got it to work, but I think it is hacky. I first have to create an array of the given size so that I can append these values, and I have to delete the initialized value the first time I append my found value. I then sweep through my the space on my graph and find a y-value, first by guessing high, second by guessing low, in order to find both possible y-values. I put these found values at the front and back of D, in order to plot this using matplotlib.

```
D = np.array([[0], [0]])
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
a_iter, b_iter = 0, 0   # used as initial guess for numeric solver
for xx in range(x_min, x_max):
    # used to print top and bottom sides of hyperbola
    yya = fsolve(lambda yy: W[:,0] + W[:,1]*xx**2 + W[:,2]*yy**2 + W[:,3]*xx*yy + W[:,4]*xx + W[:,5]*yy, max(a_iter, 7))
    yyb = fsolve(lambda yy: W[:,0] + W[:,1]*xx**2 + W[:,2]*yy**2 + W[:,3]*xx*yy + W[:,4]*xx + W[:,5]*yy, b_iter)
    a_iter = yya
    b_iter = yyb
    # add these points to a single matrix for printing
    dda = np.array([[xx],[yya]])
    ddb = np.array([[xx],[yyb]])
    D = np.concatenate((dda, D), axis=1)
    if xx == x_min: # delete initial [0; 0]
        D = dda
    D = np.concatenate((D, ddb), axis=1)
```

I know there has to be a better way to do this. Any insight is appreciated.

**Edit**: Apologies, I realize that without an image this is really difficult to understand. The main issue of finding multiple roots and populating a numpy array are a bit generic. I don't have enough rep to post images, but the link is below
[nonlinear classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxKDu.png)

Comment: I know you are very deep into the subject, but most others aren't. So please put yourself in the position of someone who has not spent the last days on classification problems - would they understand your question? I guess not. So it makes sense to review it and clearly state the actual problem. Also make the problem reproducible, use a [mcve] and show the code's output. Possibly use a plot of the data to explain the problem.

Comment: If you have the analytic solution, what exactly is tripping you up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want plot an implicit equation curve, you can use `pyplot.contour()`, here is an example:

```
np.random.seed(1)
w = np.random.randn(6)

def f(x, y, w):
    return w[0] + w[1]*x**2 + w[2]*y**2 + w[3]*x*y + w[4]*x + w[5]*y

X, Y = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j]

pl.contour(X, Y, f(X, Y, w), levels=[0])
```

Comment: top of my **"python plot branches hyperbola"** search: http://blog.mmast.net/conics-matplotlib scroll to bottom

Comment: I was missing the 'branches' part of that query. My google-fu failed me. pyplot.countour seems like a much better way of doing all this than how I went about it

Answer (score 0):

there are parameterized options too - a trig one, branches centered at 0, pi

```
t = np.linspace(-np.pi/3, np.pi/3, 200)  # 0 centered branch

y = 1/np.cos(t) 
x = 1*np.tan(t)
plt.plot(x, y)  # (default blue)
Out[94]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xe26e6a0>]

t = np.linspace(np.pi-np.pi/3, np.pi+np.pi/3, 200)  # pi centered branch

y = 1/np.cos(t) 
x = 1*np.tan(t)
plt.plot(x, y)  # (default orange)
Out[96]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xf68e780>]
```

[image]

`sympy` ought to be up to finding the full denormalized, rotated, offset parameterized hyperbola coefficients from the bivariate polynomial `w`s
(or continue the hackage with a fit)